# Html5 drag and drop accidentally activate css:hover style

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is really weird,the code is really simple,index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width:300px;
            list-style:none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .box>li{
            width:100px;
            background-color: black;
            opacity:0.7;
            color: white;
            height: 100px;
            float:left;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;
        }

        .box>li:hover{
            opacity:1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="box">
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
        <li draggable="true">drag me</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

run this code and drag one li element to another and drop,then activate the :hover style of a random li element but just not of the li element under the mouse point,happened both in safari and chrome in mac os,not happened in windows.

do you have any suggestions to avoid this bug

Comment: Can't repro Safari 9.0.2 and chrome 47. But whatever you want to do with draggable elements, you should handle the drag events with javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: What I want to do is drag the element to the blank area at right side and drop then I will add something to the right side,of course I handle the drag events,and I achieved this functionality cross browser,including handling the  firefox's ```event.dataTransfer``` you mentioned below,the only issue is when I drag the element  and drop it at the left side,some other elements :hover style is triggered.

Comment: and I thought this issue is not caused by what we do in the drag events handler,but I wonder whether is there any way such as ```e.preventDefault()``` to prevent this in drag events,I tired and didn't work.

Comment: Once again, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, neither on chrome nor Safari nor FF on my mac. Can you provide a full snippet exemple where it does happen?

Comment: did you test this code in online editor like jsFindle or plunker, if so,you will not see this issue,put the code file on you machine or on your website server and you may see it,

Comment: thanks for you patience,there are two gif images here,show the phenomenon happened to me.https://github.com/fenyiwudian/practice_demo/issues/1

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the example of [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp) may be this will help you.

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's problem ?

Comment: I thought because his items are not dragging!

Comment: Because you do use Firefox which does need that the `event.dataTransfer` be set before handling the drag. But it isn't even mantionned in the link you provided...